# How to batch send existing Purchase Orders through a new PO Output Condition?

Tags: edi, sap-erp

Our company has recently integrated with an existing supplier through EDI. The supplier has requested re-output of all existing PO's through EDI to sync their system.

We use **tcode `MN04`** to establish the output condition, which works just fine for new POs. However, is anyone aware of a method to, in a batch, re-output the existing PO's through this new medium (EDI)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ME9F to generate outputs for a selection of Purchase orders.

Later.....

Comment: Thank you so much for this response! Looks like this is a promising solution; however, when attempting to execute for a given PO, the document is not found because that output condition is not yet included on the PO. How can I make sure the new output condition is present for the older POs I wish to send?

Answer (score 0):

You can use standard program `SD70AV1A`. It is intended especially for sales orders.